# Counting the number of numbers in a range of cells

Tags: excel, counting, vba

I am trying to find a formula in an Excel VBA that will count the number of numbers in a range of cells. I have tried a formula but it only counts the number of numbers within a single cell.  Can anyone help me with this?

```
=IF(A1="",0,LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",""))+1)
```

Comment: well it would need to specify the range of cells. i think excel is nice in letting you build these functions almost-automatically

Answer (score 2):

Paste this code in a module

```
Function GetNumbCount(Rng As Range) As Long
    Dim aCell As Range
    Dim MYAr As Variant
    Dim n As Long, i As Long

    For Each aCell In Rng
        If InStr(1, aCell.Value, " ") Then
            MYAr = Split(aCell.Value, " ")
            For i = LBound(MYAr) To UBound(MYAr)
                If IsNumeric(Trim(MYAr(i))) Then n = n + 1
            Next i
        Else
            If IsNumeric(Trim(aCell.Value)) Then n = n + 1
        End If
    Next

    GetNumbCount = n
End Function
```

And then use it in a worksheet

**Syntax**

*GetNumbCount(Range)*

**ScreenShot**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Cannot understand what is needed and why, but to sum the results of the given formula in the range `A1:B2`, you could use an array formula like this:

`{=SUM(IF(A1:B2="",0,LEN(A1:B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1:B2," ",""))+1))}`

Use Ctrl+Shift+Enter to enter the formula as an array one

Comment: what result your formula would give you for cell with value `1 d a b`?

Comment: @simoco 4, but this is not my formula (only sum part is). For Siddharth Rout inputs from the picture it gives 11

Comment: SiddhartRout checks whether the value is numeric :`If IsNumeric(Trim(MYAr(i)))` but you not. I know that this is OP's formula, but you should be mentioned that it works only in case when cells contains only numbers delimited with spaces:)

Comment: The question says that the original formula does the job for a single cell and asks about ranges. I just didn't make any additional assumptions missing from it.